What kind of alcohol should I use to infuse garnish for an old fashion?
My son loves the Old Fashion drink he gets at his favorite restaurant. They marinate the blackberries in some kind of alcohol and I want to make some of alcohol infused blackberries as a surprise for his birthday. Can you tell me what to do? Thank you!

An Old Fashioned doesn’t have blackberries in it. Were they a garnish, or muddled in, or what? And are you planning to make blackberries with alcohol soaked into them, or more like a blackberry liqueur with blackberries in it?

When it comes to steeping the berries in alcohol, I think that broadly speaking, you have three main options. A flavorless spirit such as vodka, a spirit that will accentuate the berry flavour, and the same or a similar whisky to which your son likes in his Old Fashioned. Each approach has its advantages and its drawbacks though.

Vodka
The advantages of using Vodka is that it's a more neutrally flavoured spirit. So it shouldn't bring its own strong flavours. You and your son should also be able to used the berries in other, non-whisky based cocktails, or in baking for example. There's also the added advantage that a decent, neutral flavoured Vodka is likely to be cheaper than a decent whisky.

Accentuate the Positive / Blackberries
Blackberry Liqueur, Blackberry Schnapps, or Crème de Mûre as it is known to cocktail nerds, is a blackberry infused, brandy or vodka based Liqueur. If your aim was to get the maximum level of blackberry flavour into the marinated blackberries, then using a blackberry Liqueur may be worth considering... the downside is though, that Crème de Mûre may be more difficult to get hold of, and it's probably gonna be a one trick pony, the remnants of which will end up in the back of a cupboard until you or your son has a hankering for blackberry Schnapps. It could also (and I am just theorizing here rather than talking from experience) be overpowering or maybe it could detract from the unique flavour and freshness of the blackberries you'll use... Having said that though, it could also be great.

Whisky
When you steep things in alcohol, it takes time for the flavours to really mingle and integrate into one another. So perhaps steeping them in your son's whisky of choice may mean that the berries can really have time to mix with the whisky. Which could result in a more balanced cocktail. The other advantage of this is that you wouldn't have to worry about the flavour you steep the berries in clashing with the whisky in the Old Fashioned, because they'll be the same. I don't think that would be too much of an issue with a decent, neutral vodka though, as good Vodka is meant to provide the alcohol content without imparting its own flavours. If you were to steep them in the Crème de Mûre though, as it's Brandy based, *perhaps" it could be an issue.
The downside of using your son's whisky of choice is that it too could clash with the whisky in the event that your son tries another type of whisky in his cocktail. Again, it's not likely to be a major problem unless your son prefers a very distinctly flavoured whisky, such as something that is heavily peated or very smokey.

Personally, if I were in your position, I'd be inclined toward using Vodka. Something unflavoured and something that has been triple filtered (or more) as it should mean the flavour will be neutral.
As Vodka is less likely to bring any flavours of its own, it'll probably be more versatile, and Vodka itself can be used in numerous different ways. So if you have leftovers, you can drink it, cook with it... heck, some people even clean with it!
Good luck, and Happy Birthday to your son!

[EDIT] One thing I forgot to mention is that if the restaurant where your son drinks the Old Fashioned is fairly popular, especially if it's part of a chain, then it might be worth looking to see if anyone has recreated the recipe.

Question was about Blackberries, not blue, but advice still applies.

@bob1 that was a total brain fart on my part. I was typing in a bit of a hurry. I'll further edit my answer to reflect the different berry.
